# php get css class and assign it to rel attribute

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-match-all, partial

How do I take this:

```
<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />
```

search for the word "align" in the class array, take the remainder of the word "align" (in this case "left") and assign it to an actual align property?

```
<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" align="LEFT" src="xxxx" />
```

I know I need

```
$needle = "align";
$haystack = "<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />"
```

and what I'm looking for is

```
$pincushion = {{the rest of the word from $needle}}
```

so basically I'm doing a `preg_match` for `$needle`. If found, how do I get the rest of that word (i.e., `$pincushion`) ?

I tried `preg_split` but it wouldn't allow me to use "align" as a delimiter. (makes sense)

This can NOT be jquery / javascript - it must take place in the rendered html code.

Any thoughts? I've spent 10 hours now searching for an answer with no real luck.
I did come across DomDocument but couldn't make that find what I needed either.

Comment: php regex question
How do I take this
img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" /
search for "align" and get the rest of that word - to apply to the align attribute
img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" align="LEFT" src="xxxx" /
the regex is killing me - too many moving parts.

I know I need
$needle = "align";
$haystack = "img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" /"

And what I'm looking for is
$pincushion = {{the rest of the word from $needle}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('#align(.*?)(" )#si', '<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => alignLEFT" 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => LEFT
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => " 
    )

)
```

Explaination: 
`#align(.*?)(" )#si` looks for algin followed by `n-chars` delimited by `"` or .

Comment: preg_match_all('#align(.*?)(" )#si', $content, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);                
    print_r($arr[0]);               doing this returned Array ( [0] => alignleft size-full image-10968" )              is this regex only supposed to go to the end of the word? or end of the line?  how would i stop it at "alignleft" and not continue on to size-full image-10968 etc?

Comment: preg_match_all('#align(.*?)(" )#si', '<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($arr[1][0]);
AHHH THERE IT IS THANK YOU!
http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/multidimensional-array-functions

Comment: one final note for anyone else... I changed preg_match_all('#align(.*?)(\b)#si, '<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT alignRIGHT" src="xxxx" />', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
ADDING (\b) allowed me to seperate at each word. rather than till the end of the " because its possible by some goofy means that there could be both alignLEFT and alignRIGHT assigned as classes. (you never know what you might encounter when others edit html)
then I brought in

Comment: used print_r($arr); to determine exactly which array key I needed
in this case it was
print_r($arr[1][0]);  which returned simply the word "LEFT" which is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I accepted your answer. This is my first time posting a question. Unfortunately its telling me I must have a reputation of 15 to upvote?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I'm still stuck on this portion. How would I compose the php regex to apply the align attribute to the image?
I see how you did it via DomDocument -= unfortunately =- that method won't work in this case as I need to filter the_content in wordpress. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction. I'm a novice to php. Doing all I can to actually learn it. Not just hack at solutions. I want to really understand the language.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with HTML you can get DOMDocument to work.  It's a bit more drawn out, but probably easier to read and change than a complicated regex

There are libraries out there that are better at dealing with HTML fragments than domdocument, but if you want to use built in functions, domdocument is the way to go.

```
<?php

$html = '<img class="" src="xxxx" />adasdasdasd<img class="classone twoclass alignLEFT" src="xxxx" />';

$domdoc = new DOMDocument('');
$domdoc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($domdoc);

$imgs = $xpath->query('//img');


foreach ($imgs as $element) {

    $class = $element->getAttribute('class');

    if (strpos($class, 'alignLEFT') !== false) {

        $element->setAttribute('align', 'left');
    }

}

// DOM Document works with full html documents, so now we have to isolate our fragment

$bodyelement = $xpath->query('/html/body');
$bodyhtml = $domdoc->saveXML($bodyelement->item(0));

echo str_replace(array('<body>', '</body>'), '', $bodyhtml);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  Where I'm having problems is using "align" as the search parameter and getting the rest of the word.  alignleft or alignright or alignnone are most common.  I'd like to return "left" or "right" or "none" respectively for the align portion